# Node.js - using JSON objects as variables

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

As part of a test scenario, I would like to use some large JSON objects. I would like to store  these in a separate directory, and then import each object as I need them.

Currently I am using the following method:

```
var t1 = require('./sample_data/t1.json')

var t2 = require('./sample_data/t2.json')
```

however am seeing out of date data, im guessing due to require cache.

I have tried exporting each object, however I then get a wrapper object around the JSON I require that breaks my tests

Can anyone advise? Is there a better way to do this?

Regards, Ben.

UPDATE: My issue is that I see cached results as I tweak the stored JSON

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: what are the 'strange results' ?

Comment: Updated. Apologies for not being clear.

Comment: I think he means that when he updates the JSON file while running his app, the app returns the old version. This is the behavior of the require() function: Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know if its a better way but you can also do it using the File System module like this:

```
fs.readFile('./sample_data/t1.json', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  t1 = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

update:

Like Nirk said, there is a synchronous version of fs.readFile. If you want to use that version, your code should look like:

```
t1 = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./sample_data/t1.json'));
```

Comment: This is relative to the current directory, not the JS file.  Also, this is async.

Answer (score 2):

Your suspicion is correct.

`require()` caches modules; it will only read each file from disk once.

You can break this cache like this:

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve('...')];
```

Alternatively, you can read the file yourself using the `fs` module, then call `JSON.parse()`.
Make sure to correctly pass a relative or absolute path (you may want to call `require.resolve()`).